# Hide angular sources behind login page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, azure

I currently have a rather large web site where everything loads in `index.html`. The first page the user will see is the login screen, but since it also runs on `index.html`, the whole web site becomes available for download without login in. My routes also become exposed through this. I know about the difficulties in securing js code on client side, but I would at least hide it from anonymous users.

My backend is ASP.NET running on Azure. This is something somewhat trivial to do on a LAMP stack, but I'm rather unsure of how it should be done here.

Is it a requirement that everything loads in a single page or can I redirect the browser somewhere else?

I've also thought of injecting `<script>` tags on the page after the login from the server side, but this feels terribly wrong.

Comment: Is this something that a framework such as RequireJS would facilitate?

Comment: I don't really know about RequireJS, but it is interesting. This looks like the framework way of doing the `<script>` trick. I still need to provide the scripts list through the server though, I'd just feel a little less dirty about it

Comment: Whatever is available in `index.html` will be visible to all, scripts, everything. You could move the scripts to their own files (and should if it's that large a site) but to go any further you will have to dynamically reference scripts via dynamic `<script>` tag placement. This too is not "secure" because anyone using DOM or network traffic inspection (eg available natively to chrome & FF) can see what was loaded. At that point you may, as a last resort, consider obfuscated production `js` files / code. They're a good deterrent but not 100% safe, 99% maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can try to use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), with which you can leverage Node.js feature `require()` and `exports` or `module.exports` to struct your Angularjs source scripts, and eventually combine them into one javascript file. And your client end only need to include this script which will load the entire Angularjs project. And also you will not expose your angularjs source code to public.

And you can use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to automates your workflows.

You also can refer to https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/using-gulp.html for how to use Gulp in ASP.NET project in VS.

Please refer to https://omarfouad.com/ for detailed information and get started steps about building Angularjs structure with Browerify and Gulp.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.